# Google Sheets API: batchGet returned "undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I saw previous similar post from Din.  I tried both Logger.log(response.valueRanges) and console.log.  Both returned nothing.  Hope someone can help. Below is my script.  From this script I got "undefined".

```
function getData() {
  var params = {
    spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID,
    ranges : ['Sheet1!i2'],
  };
  var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet(params);
  request.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.result.values);
  }, function(response) {
    console.log('error: ' + response.result.error.message);
  });
}
```

Comment: The error indicates that there is no property of ``values`` in ``response.result``. In the case of the method of values.batchGet, how about modifying from ``console.log(response.result.values)`` to ``console.log(response.result)``?

Comment: Yes, I think Tanaike's right. You can also add a null checker for your request just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  console.log(response.result.values) would also give me "undefined".  console.log(response.result.values.length) gives me undefined.  It is not null.  It tested at Google Sheet batchGet doc and it worked.  It is there.  Just don't know how to get it.